# How to trace the graphic of $\cos(x) + \cosh(y) = k$?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, hyperbolic-functions

Is there some systematic way to trace the graphic of

$\cos(x) + \cosh(y) = k$

given a fixed value for $k$?

Suppose $k = 1$: if I choose empirically $y = 1.2$, I know that should be

$\cos(x) = - 0.2$

and so I could find all the infinite values of $x$ which verify the equation. But is this a correct way? How can I proceed, given such an implicit equation?

Comment: Hyperbolic cosine is actually (explicitly) invertible. I'm not sure if this makes it easier, but you can change this from an implicit to explicit equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to graph $y$ in terms of $x$.

Let $z=e^y$ and note that $\cosh y = \frac{1}2(z+z^{-1})$. So $2\cos x + z+z^{-1} = 2k$. Multiplying by $z$ and rearranging, you get:

$$z^2 +2(\cos x-k)z+1 = 0$$

So $z=(k-\cos x)\pm \sqrt{(k-\cos x)^2-1}$

So $$\begin{align}y&=\log\left(k-\cos x\pm \sqrt{(k-\cos x)^2-1}\right) \\
&=\pm \log\left(k-\cos x + \sqrt{(k-\cos x)^2-1}\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for the very useful answer. I can't understand just a passage: why do you write substantially $\log(a - b) = -\log(a + b)$? Which rule do you use?

Comment: Because in this case, only, $a-b=\frac{1}{a+b}$, so $\log(a-b)=-\log(a+b)$. Basically, if $y=z+1/z$ then if $z$ is a root, $z^{-1}$ is the other root...